# Could not find symbol '$'

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, typescript

I'm referencing jquery in my typescript file but visual studio is telling me that it...

**Could not find symbol '$'**

Any ideas how to get rid of these errors?

ps - I am referencing jquery at the top of my typescript file as follows...

```
/// <reference path="./js/lib/jquery.min.js" />
```

Comment: Try using jQuery, not $

Comment: add an extra . before the first / in the path so it looks like this... <reference path="../js/lib/jquery.min.js" />

Comment: do you see any console errors like 404 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to reference the jquery definition file `jquery.d.ts`, not the javascript file. So :

```
/// <reference path="./jquery.d.ts" />
```

You can get this file from here : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery

You can see sample usage here : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery-tests.ts#L1

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to use the jQuery definitions from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped. This way you'll gain intellisense, typechecking etc as well.

The more hackish approach is to simply add:

```
declare var $;
```

This will tell typescript that the variable $ is defined somewhere else. This is useful at times where there are no definitions available, or when you don't care about having working intellisense.